# wordpress post_content in headers for meta tags

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

my title cell is blank so i want to show post_content data in my meta description tag.

when i give some details in title then it works but for content details it is not working.
when i use  the_content it works but it shows google adsense data however in my mysql cell there is no adsense code.

i have tried this in my header.php file of wordpress

```
<?php 

 $content = get_the_content();
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
 $postn991=strip_tags($content);
 echo' <meta name="description" content="'.$postn991.'" />';
   ?>
```

i have tried post_content,blog_content almost all possible combination but its not working.

the above code gives something in meta but its google ads.and i want to fetch data of post_content from mysql in meta name content

Answer (score 1):

solved this issue with below code

```
 $p = get_post($pid);
$description = strip_tags($p->post_content);
   $postn991=strip_tags($description);
```

Comment: Thank you. Very handy as it's outside the "loop" in header.php.